# What is Binding energy/the energy required to for a nucleus to form a result of?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

Is it simply the work required to overcome the electrostatic repulsion of protons, or rather the coloumb barrier potential between nuclei?

If so where does the effective of tunneling come in, as binding energy are stated as distinct values?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Did you do any prior research about the topic by yourself?

Comment: Related reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force  although you will have to search deeper for the tunnelling aspect.